# OpenCV FAST - too many features

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection, keypoint

I'm trying to extract features so I can later train a SVM which will be used in Android app. I'm using python to find and extract the features because it is easy to write and saves time. My problem is that I get too many features and I don't know how to get the best features only. I found that there is a method retainBest in the C++ API of OpenCV but I couldn't find it for python. Can you give an advise what to do?

This is the code I use:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('./positive_images/1.jpg',cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
#img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./positive_images/3.png',cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE), (100, 100))
#th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
ret,th3 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
cv2.imwrite("result1.jpg", th3)

img = th3

# Initiate FAST object with default values
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector()

# find and draw the keypoints
keypoints = fast.detect(img,None)
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, color=(255,0,0))

cv2.imwrite('fast_true.png',img2)

# Disable nonmaxSuppression
fast.setBool('nonmaxSuppression',0)
keypoints = fast.detect(img,None)

print "Total Keypoints without nonmaxSuppression: ", len(keypoints)

img3 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, color=(255,0,0))
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg",img3)
```

The original image:

[image]

And the result image:

[image]

My goal is to detect a steering wheel.

Comment: keypoints have a 'response' member. you could simply try to filter out the weakest ones.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll look at that (I hope I'll have better results).

Comment: still remember, that the whole keypoint/feature detection thing will find *exactly this specific model*. (you probably can't detect *arbitrary* wheels this way.

Comment: well that's why I'm going to train an SVM and also I wont use only this picture.

Comment: Steering wheels don't have features that jump out as much as their overall outline does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#fastfeaturedetector), you will see that you can set a threshold for your FAST detector:

```
FastFeatureDetector( int threshold=1, bool nonmaxSuppression=true, type=FastFeatureDetector::TYPE_9_16 );
```

Here, the default `threshold` is set to 1. In your code, try to set it to 40, and see the results, as follows:

```
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector(40)
```

You will find details about the meaning of the threshold [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html#feature-detection-using-fast):

1. Select a pixel p in the image which is to be identified as an interest point or not. Let its intensity be I_p
2. ...
3. ...
4. Now the pixel p is a corner if there exists a set of n contiguous pixels in the circle (of 16 pixels) which are all brighter than I_p + t, or all darker than I_p − t. (Shown as white dash lines in the above image). n was chosen to be 12.

Comment: Don't you have the same constructor in Python?

Comment: Well I'm trying to find the documentation but for some reason I can't

Comment: Did you try `fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector(40)`?

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that, I'm really sorry. Yes it worked. Thank you very much! Would you add your python line from your comment to your answer? I'll mark it as accepted then.